# Desearializing a JSON which comes with an empty field

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON object like this:

```
public class Example { 
private String a; 
private int b; 
private SubDataExample c; 
//more fields, constructor, getters, etc
} 

public class SubDataExample{ 
private String d; 
private int e; 
//more fields, constructor, getters, etc 
}
```

It works well most cases, but sometimes SubData doesn't bring any 
data, I get JSON like this:

```
{"a":"blabla", b:843849, c:""}
```

Then, GSON fails and I get an exception. Would be possible to fill 
with a null the "c" field in the deserialized object?

I'm consuming a webservice that I haven't made, so, I have no option 
about changing the JSON that has to be deserialized.

I would appreciate your help

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that if there is no `SubDataExample`, then you should get

```
{ "a": "blabla", "b": 843849, "c": null }
```

or

```
{ "a": "blabla", "b": 843849 }
```

Comment: You are right. The JSON which came was indeed bad formed, so, Gson, obviously, failed.

Comment: So, if this is the right answer, you are supposed to accept the answer, and click on "^" ('this answer is useful').